# Cannot access USB drive which is encytped

Tags: usb-drive

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 Desktop 64bit. I previously had version 14.x. I put x in as I cannot remember the exact version.

I have an encypted USB drive which when attached to my laptop running ubuntu gives me the following message:

"Unable to mount 3.8 GB Encrypted"

Please advise on what I can do to resolve this. I am new to linux.

Comment: How was it encrypted? Hardware encryption? LUKS? A TrueCrypt partition?

Comment: And, more important, do you know the passphrase?

Comment: I believe it was LUKS. Yes I know the passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

After plugging in your USB drive, type:

```
lsblk
```

This will show you the device node of your encrypted drive e.g. `/dev/sdc`.

Then, decrypt the drive:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc my_encrypted_drive
```

Type your passphrase. Now the drive can be mounted:

```
mount /dev/mapper/my_encrypted_drive /mnt
```

Once you've finished using it, unmount and encrypt it again:

```
umount /mnt
cryptsetup luksClose my_encrypted_drive
```

Comment: After typing the command to mount the drive and I got the following message:  mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'. I have installed via the following command sudo apt-get install lvm2 but still getting same message.

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo pvs`.

Comment: /dev/mapper/my_encrypted_drive ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  3.55g 16.00m

Comment: Can you please run the following commands: `sudo pvscan`, `sudo vgscan`, `sudo lvscan` and post the output?

Comment: `sudo pvscan`  
`PV /dev/mapper/my_encrypted_drive   VG ubuntu-vg   lvm2 [3.55 GiB / 16.00 MiB free]`  
`Total: 1 [3.55 GiB] / in use: 1 [3.55 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]`

Comment: `sudo vgscan`  
`Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...`  
`Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2`

Comment: `sudo lvscan`  
`ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/root' [1.42 GiB] inherit`  
`ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1' [168.00 MiB] inherit`  
`ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/home' [1.95 GiB] inherit`

Comment: Can anybody else help?